# inserting and retrieving audio and video from database

Tags: c#

I did a small web application in which i have made use of windows media player dll. To play the audio and video file and i have uploaded audio and video by creating a folder in the application.

And the media player which i have used is only possible to play audio and video if we give the  path directly like

MediaPlayer1.FileName="C:\Waka.wav";

so please help me how to insert and retrieve audio and video in database and in a player.

Comment: @Hinek .. Not new.. Check other questions for this person and you ahve the same comment;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is the media player playing the file on the server or on the client?  You say it's a web application, so I'm currently assuming the latter.  If your claim that the media player can *only* use local paths is true, then you'll have to have the client download the file to a local path and pass that to the media player.  It won't make for a particularly fluid user experience.  Does the media player really not accept URLs as paths?  If this is the case then it sounds like you might be using a media player that doesn't suit your needs.  Consider using a different one.

Also, why is the file being served from a database?  File systems and web servers are really good at serving files, I'd recommend using those instead.  A relational database is good for relational data that can be indexed, sorted, pivoted, etc.  It's usable for binary files, but it's not really suited for them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using media player dll use `<embed/>` tag browser will choose the media player for the user and this will be platform independent.

Why do you want to make use of database for saving files as @David say's you can store it on server file system. In your `<embed/>` tag you can specify the path on the server.